# Creating a List from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make a list of all items in a binary search tree. I understand the recursion but I don't know how to make it return each value and then append it into a list. I want to create a function called `makeList()` that will return a list of all the items in my tree. All the functions in my programs work except the `makeList()` function and are included to make sure everyone understands the basic structure of how I set up my tree.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.lChild = None
        self.rChild = None

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def __str__(self):
        current = self.root

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def insert (self, item):
        newNode = Node (item)
        current = self.root
        parent = self.root

        if self.root == None:
            self.root = newNode
        else:
            while current != None:
                parent = current
                if item < current.data:
                    current = current.lChild
                else:
                    current = current.rChild

            if item < parent.data:
                parent.lChild = newNode
            else:
                parent.rChild = newNode

    def inOrder(self, aNode):
        if aNode == None:
            pass
        if aNode != None:
            self.inOrder(aNode.lChild)
            print aNode.data
            self.inOrder(aNode.rChild)

    def makeList(self, aNode):
        a = []
        self.inOrder(aNode)
        a += [aNode.data]
        print a

n = Tree()
for i in [4,7,2,9,1]:
    n.insert(i)

n.makeList(n.root)
```

Looking at my `makeList()` function I can see why it doesn't work but I don't know how to make it work.

**EDIT**

Ok, I got it! And I even got two answers which are:

```
def makeList(self, aNode, a = []):
    if aNode != None:
        self.makeList(aNode.lChild, a)
        a += [aNode.data]
        self.makeList(aNode.rChild, a)
    return a
```

and

```
def makeList2(self, aNode):
    if aNode is None:
        return []
    return self.makeList2(aNode.lChild) + [aNode.data] + self.makeList2(aNode.rChild)
```

And looking back I can see that I do not understand recursion very well so it's time to hit the books! Anyone have any good resources on recursion?

Another question, so say I call my `makeList()` function. When Python goes through `makeList()`, when it gets to the `self.makeList(aNode.lChild, a)` does it begin running the function again while it's still finishing up the `makeList()` function or does everything stop and it just starts over with it's new `aNode`?

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you want to read a book on recursion of tree, I want to recommend "Programming Interviews Exposed: Secrets to Landing Your Next Job by John Mongan".

Comment: Avoid using mutable default values for arguments in function signatures.
These mutable values are being evaluated once, during the function definition (and not its call), thus it can be a culprit for many weird bugs.
Basically many function calls will use the same mutable object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're so close! makeList can be pretty simple:

```
def makeList(self, aNode):
    if aNode is None:
        # Stop recursing here
        return []
    return self.makeList(aNode.lChild) + [aNode.data] + self.makeList(aNode.rChild)
```

Basically, make sure you're not trying to recurse past empty nodes. Then return the list of the left tree, the current node, and the list of the right tree.

Comment: haha you guys are making me think! I'm gonna work on it for a bit and get back to y'all!

Comment: What happend if left or right leaf is none?

Answer (score 1):

`inOrder` prints things but does not return anything, so it's useless for building a list. You need a way to **return** each node in order. This may be something that your class hasn't covered yet, but check out the `yield` command.

Comment: Yes, an iterator would make it easy to both print the tree and produce a flattened list from it, and would be generally useful to other users of the class as well. Iterators++

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is something like this:

```
def makeList(self):
    return self.lChild.makeList() + [self.data] + self.rChild.makeList()
```

See how it is essentially the same thing as inOrder?

You have a different structure in your program that makes it a bit harder to implement, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Now I do see how it's basically the same. It's just very tough to visualize.

Comment: Thanks. This code works on combined Node and Tree Classes code.